# Does MySql full text search works reasonably with non-Latin languages (Hebrew, Arabic, Japanese...)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, non-latin

Does MySql full text search works reasonably with non-Latin languages? (Hebrew, Arabic, Japanese...)

Addition: Did some tests... It has some problems with Hebrew. Example: The name *מו**ס**ינזון* is pronounced the same as *מו**ש**ינזון* but searching one won't find the other, as this is a common spelling error in Hebrew, it seems I will have to do some data manipulation for it to work perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to catch Hebrew semantics. If it were set to a Hebrew collation, my guess is that it would.

Comment: There is no Hebrew collation for utf8. I guess we do it the hard way.

Answer (score 4):

Though Hebrew support in MySQL is limited, your problem is more a problem of people using incorrect spelling, then a dysfunction of the MySQL server in this perspective. When you misspell a word in Google, it will show you a suggestion and you can click on that suggestion to search for that term.

Perhaps you could build some program that has the same behaviour, e.g. you could create a table that has 2 fields, one containing the commonly misspelled word and the other containing the correct spelling. You could then build a program that finds the misspelled word and displays the suggestion.

Comment: The usual way to implement this is using n-grams

Answer (score 2):

So long as your [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html) is set properly, it works splendidly.

Unicode will work for most of this, of course. But that doesn't really translate Latin characters to them very well (for example, in a Dutch collation `aa` will be recognized as `å`).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** MySQL fulltext search works well for **Arabic**. Just make sure of the following where needed:

1. **`COLLATION = utf8_unicode_ci`** & **`CHARACTER SET = utf8`**. (Databases, Tables, and Columns).
2. **Index words of 3 letters and more**. This is **Very Important** for Arabic, `ft_min_word_len = 3` (see `show variables like "ft_%";`)
3. Check the version of MySQL (5.5 or 5.6), and Engine (InnoDb or MyIsam)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however, check out what [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) are.

Answer (score 1):

`Japanese` and `Chinese` use their own whitespace symbols that `MySQL` does not understand.

Make sure that the words in the texts you are going to index are separated with `ASCII` separators (spaces, commas etc). Anything outside the `ASCII` range will probably not work.

Besides, you'll probably need to fix `ft_min_word_len`: by default, `MySQL` won't index words shorter than `4` characters, and most `Japanese` and `Chinese` words.

In `Cyrillic` languages transilteration errors are quite common.

All letters from this sequence: `АВЕКМНОРСТуХ / ABEKMHOPCTyX` are indistinguishable in most fonts.

The worst of them is Cyrillic `С`/ Latin `C`: both these symbols are located on one key on the keyboard and do not differ at all in most fonts, but they have different codes.

`MySQL` will not catch it either.